# Complex regular expression to capture specific words but not partial words

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble coming up with a regular expression that matches all instances of the given words but does not match partials. The text that I am scanning will be raw HTML.

Here is my current regex:

```
/(|>|^|;|,| )(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)(<| |\.|;|,|\!|\?|\)|$)/i
```

That regex will match the words in bold:

> Always check Agile for the latest version of applicable Service and
>   Installation procedures! The steps contained in this database are for
>   Troubleshooting only, not for performing Service. This is not a
>   controlled document and may not be distributed **to** non-Stryker
>   personnel
>
> **christmas** holiday **christmas** christmas **holiday** is something **detroit**
>   **christmas** holiday

If I modify the regex to:

```
/(|>|^|;|,| )?(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)(<| |\.|;|,|\!|\?|\)|$)/i
```

The regex matches the following:

> Always check Agile for the la**test** version of applicable Service and Installation procedures! The steps contained in t**his** database are for Troubleshooting only, not for performing Service. T**his** is not a controlled document and may not be distributed **to** non-Stryker personnel
>
> **christmas holiday christmas christmas holiday** is something **detroit** **christmas holiday**

The second version matches all the words that it should but because of the ? modifier it is also matching partials which I want to skip. How can I modify the regex so that a match of "christmas " does not steel the space from the next possible match?

Comment: Maybe `\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)\b`? What is the `christmas ` you are trying to match? What language/platform are you running this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b`, and I think you would like to match more than one group per line (`g` at the end):

```
/\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)\b/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/xJ5xW6/1

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what regexp engine you are using, but the standard way to do what you need, in e.g. Perl, if the engine has it, is the zero-width word boundary specifier `\b`:

```
/(|>|^|;|,| )?\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)\b(<| |\.|;|,|\!|\?|\)|$)/i
```

And to your second question, the standard way to keep the engine from "consuming" text is to use a "lookahead" match `(?=...)`, which requires the lookahead regexp to be there but does not consume it (so available for subsequent matching):

```
/(|>|^|;|,| )\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)\b(?=<| |\.|;|,|\!|\?|\)|$)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundary `\b`?

```
/\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)\b/gi
```

Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/sJ3jM2/1

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
/\b(detroit|to|christmas|holiday|test|his)+\b/gi
```

Comment: Not quite: this will match `toto` or `detroitchristmas`. You want the `+` to include the `/b`s